# WPF, DataGrid. Растягивание колонок при появлении свободного места

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

В окне есть DataGrid, при нехватке места для отображения данных появляется скрол, но если места становится больше чем необходимо появляется пустой столбец. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нехватке места появлялся скрол, но при появлении свободного места столбцы равномерно растягивались на всю доступную таблице ширину.
Текущий код таблицы:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="DataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single"/>
```

Вид при нехватке места:
[image: Вид при нехватке места]

Вид при избытке места:
[image: Вид при избытке места]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установите свойство `ColumnWidth` в `*`. Это приведет к равномерному растягиванию всех столбцов таблицы. Также в сочетании с этим свойством можете установить каким-то столбцам свою ширину.

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column1" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column2"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column3"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid/>
```

столбцы 2 и 3 поделят между собой всю свободную ширину, тем самым не будет видно "пустого столбца".

UDP: Если таблица имеет фиксированную ширину то, для появления горизонтального скрола, можно сделать так:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*"  
                  Width="500"                     
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding }">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="column1" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="column2" Binding="{Binding }"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="column3" Binding="{Binding }"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Ваше решение убирает пустой столбец, но также убирает полосу прокрутки при недостатке места для отображения данных. Мне нужно оставить полосу прокрутки.

Comment: @mirypoko, интересный эффект

Comment: @mirypoko, обновил